# Admob IOS swift GDPR consent

Tags: ios, swift, admob, admob-cookieconsent

I'm new to swift and iOS programming. I want to add Admob consent/GDPR option to my app, 
So I've setup an ad box and can display a test add, but need to add consent option next.

I've read 
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent

but it's not clear to me, can anyone show me an example of code to do this step by step, or point me to GitHub source where it has been done.

Thanks

Comment: Which step are you up to? That guide is pretty straight forward as to what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show an example of what you have tried that isn't working for you?

As I am unable to see your code example to see what you're doing or not doing, I'll give an example based on the docs.

```
import PersonalizedAdConsent
```

...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.
    requestConsentInfoUpdate(
    forPublisherIdentifiers: ["pub-0123456789012345"])
    {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
      if let error = error {
        // Consent info update failed.
      } else {
        // Consent info update succeeded. The shared PACConsentInformation
        // instance has been updated.
      }
    }

guard let privacyUrl = URL(string: "https://www.your.com/privacyurl"),
  let form = PACConsentForm(applicationPrivacyPolicyURL: privacyUrl) else {
    print("incorrect privacy URL.")
    return
}
form.shouldOfferPersonalizedAds = true
form.shouldOfferNonPersonalizedAds = true
form.shouldOfferAdFree = true


form.load {(_ error: Error?) -> Void in
  print("Load complete.")
  if let error = error {
    // Handle error.
    print("Error loading form: \(error.localizedDescription)")
  } else {
    // Load successful.
  }
}

//Finally present the consent form
form.present(from: self) { (error, userPrefersAdFree) in
      if let error = error {
        // Handle error.
      } else if userPrefersAdFree {
        // User prefers to use a paid version of the app.
      } else {
        // Check the user's consent choice.
        let status =
             PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus
      }
    }

      }
```

Comment: so at moment my viewController.swift has the test banner  code displaying to a 320x50 UIVIEW that works, I updated Podfiles added : PersonalizedAdConsent, that is there to use, but I've no idea how to use it ? I've tried google but can't find any examples which is strange as its mandatory I would think for anyone using Admob

Comment: As I am unable to see your code example to see what you're doing or not doing, I'll explain based on what google provides in their docs.

Comment: thanks for update I will try this I also found reference on git to : https://github.com/crashoverride777/swifty-ad, which I will try as well,

Comment: Error Domain=Consent Code=1 "Form not loaded." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Form not loaded.} ???